# Django: automatically detect the tenant media folder when reading csv in Views.py

Tags: django, pandas

In my multi-tenant django app, the user needs to upload a file to the server. this file is then used in a view.

my view uses pd.read_csv() to read the file uploaded, however I cannot find anywhere what to use inside of the brackets to automatically look inside of this particular tenant media folder.

Thanks to django documentation, I was able to seperate my tenants within the media folder but I still don't how to write the path inside of the pandas.read_csv()

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `BASE_DIR` gives you the project root and joining with 'mediafolder' will give you the media path. Is that what you're looking?

Comment: actually i just found out, django is smart and it knows which tenant mediafile to populate automatically from a regular path inside of the pd.read_csv function. I was looking for nothing

Comment: Hey you can also answer your own question.

Comment: @RajaSimon I was wrong, it is actually giving errors after a few tests. Would have an idea on how to fix it?